# How do I get information in one column into 2 new columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe of teachers and chaperones on a school trip.

Index | Name | Class | Number_Of_Students | Bus_Number

---

The names in the 'Name' column are listed like: Surname, Mx. Forename MiddleInitial

I am trying to split the 'Name' column into two separate columns: Surname | Forename

This is what I have tried:

```
ChaperoneName = df['Name']
df = df.assign( Surname = ChaperoneName[0], Forename = ChaperoneName[2])
```

The idea was if I isolated the one column, I could slice the strings in each row to get the Surname and the Forename into their new respective columns. But this has not worked for me. All I get in return are 2 properly named columns, but with the 0 and 2 indexed names repeating in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Surname'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0])
df['Forename'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[1])
```

Comment: When I do this, it just repeats the 0 and 2 names in the index. So I have a Surname column with every row as Smith, Mr. John K. and a Forename column with every row as Jones, Dr. Ellen L.

Comment: Try to do it now

Comment: df= df.assign(
  df['Surname'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[0]), 
  df['Forename'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[2])
)

This returns as syntax error: expression cannot contain assign.

Comment: Use the code exactly how it, is don't do df.assign

Comment: This returns the first letter of the last name in that row for Column Surname, and the third letter of the name in that row for Column Forename.

Comment: Maybe splitting the string would work?